# What is the best way to handle System.Process values in a Haskell library?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell by converting my OCaml programs which are themselves conversions of old Pick Basic programs.  I use ncurses (am trying vty-ui in Haskell) combined with a self-written library that maintains an open session to Tk's wish as a start at eventually converting to a full GUI, but mainly just used for reports, error popups, and other user feedback.

I don't want the calling program to have to pass the I/O handles and process Id with every call.  I've tried Data.Global but can't figure out how to store the process Id.  On the initial call,

```
(hin, hout, herr, hproc) <- runInteractiveCommand "wish"
...
let gvProc = declareMVar "wish-proc" hproc
```

gives a compiler error "No instance for (Data.Typeable.Internal.Typeable ProcessHandle) arising from a use of "declareMVar"

If I try to put the declaration at a top level:

```
gvProc = declareMVar "wish-proc" ???What do I put here???
```

But perhaps there's a better way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem with `Data.Global` looks like a missing `Typeable` instance.  You can fix that as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Typeable
import System.Process
deriving instance Typeable (ProcessHandle)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm always curious as to how I was supposed to figure that out myself.

Comment: @Babu Alas, missing instance errors are some of GHC's most confusing error messages, and interpreting them is a bit of an art. Much of the time the real reason is something completely different and you don't really want the instance at all...